# When compiling INET, veins and other libraries, sometimes you will be prompted with error: cannot load Library '/. / SRC / /

Tags: omnet++, veins

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STsDD.png)

<!> Error: Cannot load library '../../src//libveins.so': ../../src//libveins.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

End.

Comment: Is this happening while following the Veins tutorial on https://veins.car2x.org/tutorial/ ? If so, have you tried using Instant Veins from https://veins.car2x.org/documentation/instant-veins/ to see if this is a problem with Veins or with your system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar error once because I had forgotten to build VEINS and I was trying to run the example. After using Built All (Project -> Built All or ctrl+B) I didn't get this error again.

Comment: thanks a lot.but i dont solved m​​y problem。Here are the pictures of specific problems。​​

Comment: Could you check if the file is actually located in the mentioned path? Did you get any errors or warnings while building the project?

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot.but i dont solved m​​y problem。Here are the pictures of specific problems
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FKds.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please check in project references please check the dependencies and also if there are multiple veins projects. There should be only 1 veins dependency.